# GAE - Run scheduled cron jobs longer than 60 sec

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I've a pretty small cron job running every 24h on the GAE using Python. Since yesterday I receive a DeadlineExceededErrors, due to the fact, that the job exceeds 60 Sec. Like I said my job is pretty small so it won't exceed 5 minutes ever but unfortunately the 60 sec deadline.

I already know, that this is a usual problem and found a lot of links and workarounds on [Google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) but I can't solve the problem.

Does anybody know a good way to increase the deadline maximum or maybe to schedule a task asynchronous, to work around these 60 sec deadline?

Comment: According to this page, CRON jobs have a 10 minute limit so you shouldn't need to use a task: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cron job should simply [start a task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/). This will take less than a second. A a task can run for up to 10 minutes.

You may also want to learn about [different types of scaling methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine) on App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set up a backend service (module), which has no deadline.  Then add the `target: backend-module` param to your cron job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I looked for it but it seems to be deprecated https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/backends/

Comment: The concept hasn't changed.  They changed the name and the config:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/an-overview-of-app-engine  You set up a separate (backend)  service with a longer (or no) deadline timeout.  Then use the `target` param in your cron job to point to that service.  If you just need something longer than 60 seconds, and shorter than 10 minutes, then queuing up a task is s great solution.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood, so in my case queuing is perfect but I will need this in the future too! Thanks you helped me a lot with this knowledge! +1